# How to write GeoTIFF files in Delphi, possibly compressed

Tags: delphi, gis, tiff

I'm looking for a way to write GeoTIFF files in Delphi. If possible, I would like to write DEFLATE-compressed GeoTIFFs. Any hints on where to start?

Thanks for your insight :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at:
http://dspatial.sourceforge.net/

Specially at ["DSpatial-kernel-0.4.2.zip"](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dspatial/files/DSpatial/DSpatial%20v0.4.2/DSpatial-kernel-0.4.2.zip/download) file DSpGeoTIFF.pas

Comment: seems that writing isn't properly implemented yet? at least, it's still listed in the TODO (even though the description at the top of the file suggests that writing is possible ...). but at least that's a good (the only?) start.